# Are Payment API response data subject to change?

Tags: square-connect

I am using the Square Connect Payments API.

1. What are the cases in which response data is subject to change?
   (refunds seem like one)
2. Is there a way to know when certain data is not subject to change anymore?

Answer (score 0):

The Transaction object may be changed in the following ways:

1. The tender *processing_fee_money* is not immediately available in the *Charge* response. However, it will be populated for *Transaction* objects returned from the *RetrieveTransaction* or *ListTransactions* endpoints.
2. The *tender.card_details.status* could be changed from *AUTHORIZED* to *CAPTURED*.
3. The *tender.customer_id* for a card nonce charge could be populated later when a customer gets associated with the tender.
4. Refunds as you mentioned.
5. Additional fields may be added to the *Transaction* or its nested objects in the future

Comment: Thank you! I take it that you are referring to the v2 API (I am still using the v1 Payment API, but I assume it is similar).